# There is a board of size:nxm and a set of words.We need to find such a way of writing words on the board from file

Tags: java

title: There is a board of size: nxm and a set of words.We need to find such a way of writing words on the board such that one cell include at most one letter and every continuous sequence of letters read horizontally and vertically is a word from a subset of the size K of the set S acquired from file

I don't know how to get data from user in this code. I need code like I describe in the "Title". In this code words can not read from a file. 
    Does any one help me to solve it out this problem? I need solution before tomorrow. Does any one can do it for me?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;

/**
 * Solves a crossword puzzle as defined by the heuristics and variables
 */
public class CrosswordSolver {

    /**
     * Puzzle content (words / border)
     */
    private char[][] puzzle;

    /**
     * Crossword puzzle slots which all need to be fit
     */
    private CrosswordSlot[] slots;

    /**
     * Crossword Puzzle words which can be used to fill the slots
     */
    private CrosswordWord[] words;

    /**
     * Whether there are characters in the field in the puzzle
     */
    private int[][] letterUsage;

    /**
     * The number of backtracks used to try to fill the puzzle.
     */
    private int countBacktracks;

    public static final char BLANK = ' ';
    public static final char FILLED = '#';

     CrosswordSolver(char[][] puzzle, CrosswordSlot[] slots, CrosswordWord[] words) {
        this.puzzle = puzzle;
        this.slots = slots;
        this.words = words;

    }

    /**
     * Initialize the puzzle.
     */
    private void reinitialize() {
        letterUsage = new int[puzzle.length][puzzle[0].length];
        countBacktracks = 0;
    }

    /**
     * Solve the crossword puzzle.
     */
    private void solve() {
        reinitialize();
        if (fillPuzzle(0)) {
            System.out.println("Solution found!!!");
            System.out.println("Backtracks:" + countBacktracks);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No solution found!!!");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Tries to fill the puzzle starting from a slot.
     *
     * @param slot slot to start filling in from
     * @return whether the puzzle could be filled from the current slot
     */
    private boolean fillPuzzle(int slot) {
        if (slot == slots.length) {
            printPuzzle();
            return true;
        }
        for (CrosswordWord word : words) {
            if (wordFitInSlot(word, slots[slot])) {
                putWordInSlot(word, slots[slot]);
                if (fillPuzzle(slot + 1)) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    //If we need to backtrack (fillPuzzle(slot + 1) didn't work)
                    removeWordFromSlot(word, slots[slot]);
                }
            }
        }
        countBacktracks++;
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if a word fits in a slot
     *
     * @param w word to try to fit in slot
     * @param slot slot to try to fit the word into
     * @return does word fit
     */
    private boolean wordFitInSlot(CrosswordWord w, CrosswordSlot slot) {
       if (w.getWord().length() != slot.getLength() || w.isUsed()) {
            return false;
        }
        Point position = slot.getStart();
        int row = position.y;
        int column = position.x;
        for (int i = 0; i < slot.getLength(); ++i) {
            if (puzzle[row][column] != BLANK && puzzle[row][column] != w.getWord().charAt(i)) {
                return false;
            }
            column += slot.getDirection().x;
            row += slot.getDirection().y;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Puts a word inside a slot and sets the word as used.
     *
     * @param w word to put into the slot
     * @param slot slot to put word into
     */
    private void putWordInSlot(CrosswordWord w, CrosswordSlot slot) {
        Point position = slot.getStart();
        int row = position.y;
        int column = position.x;
        for (int i = 0; i < slot.getLength(); ++i) {
            puzzle[row][column] = w.getWord().charAt(i);
            letterUsage[row][column]++;
            column += slot.getDirection().x;
            row += slot.getDirection().y;
        }
        w.setUsed(true);
    }

    /**
     * Remove word from slot.
     *
     * @param w word to remove from slot
     * @param slot slot to remove the word from
     */
    private void removeWordFromSlot(CrosswordWord w, CrosswordSlot slot) {
        Point position = slot.getStart();
        int row = position.y;
        int column = position.x;
        for (int i = 0; i < slot.getLength(); ++i) {
            letterUsage[row][column]--;
            if (letterUsage[row][column] <= 0) {
                puzzle[row][column] = BLANK;
            }
            column += slot.getDirection().x;
            row += slot.getDirection().y;
        }
        w.setUsed(false);
    }

    /**
     * Print the puzzle.
     */
    public void printPuzzle() {
        printPuzzleBorder();
        for (int row = 0; row < puzzle.length; row++) {
            System.out.print("|");
            for (int col = 0; col < puzzle[row].length; col++) {
                System.out.print(puzzle[row][col] + "|");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        printPuzzleBorder();
        System.out.println();
    }

    /**
     * Print the border of the puzzle.
     */
    private void printPuzzleBorder() {
        for (int i = 0; i < puzzle[0].length * 2; ++i) {
            System.out.print("-");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {



       CrosswordSlot[] slots = {new CrosswordSlot(new Point(0, 0), new Point(1, 0), 3),
                new CrosswordSlot(new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 1), 3),
                new CrosswordSlot(new Point(2, 0), new Point(0, 1), 2),
                new CrosswordSlot(new Point(2, 1), new Point(1, 0), 3),
                new CrosswordSlot(new Point(4, 0), new Point(0, 1), 2),

        };
        char[][] smallPuzzle = {{BLANK, BLANK, BLANK, FILLED, BLANK}, {BLANK, FILLED, BLANK, BLANK, BLANK}, {BLANK, BLANK, FILLED, BLANK, FILLED}};
       try {

            String get_file = "C:/Users/xyz/Desktop/lemma.txt";
            System.out.println("File name is:"+get_file);

            FileReader fr = new FileReader(get_file);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String s1;

           FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(get_file);
           char c1;
            while ((s1 = br.readLine()) != null) {
                   c1= (char)fis.read();
                for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); ++i) {
                    char c = s1.charAt(i);
                    if (c1 == 'a' || c1 == 'v' || (c1 == 'a' && c1 == 'd' && c1 == 'v')) {
                        System.out.println(c1);

                        //CrosswordWord[] words = {new CrosswordWord("abbey"), new CrosswordWord("accommodate"), new CrosswordWord(" about")};

                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println(e);
       }


        CrosswordWord[] words = {new CrosswordWord("abb"), new CrosswordWord("acb"), new CrosswordWord("add"), new CrosswordWord("ba"), new CrosswordWord("bd")};

        CrosswordSolver s = new CrosswordSolver(smallPuzzle, slots, words);
        s.printPuzzle();
        s.solve();

    }
}

/**
 * A slot in the crossword puzzle that we will need to fill.
 */
class CrosswordSlot {
    private Point start;
    private Point direction;
    private int length;
    public CrosswordSlot(Point start, Point direction, int length) {

        this.start = start;
        this.direction = direction;
        this.length = length;

    }

    public Point getStart() {

        return start;
    }

    public Point getDirection() {

        return direction;
    }

    public int getLength() {

        return length;
    }

}

/**
 * A word that we will try to fit inside the crossword.
 */
class CrosswordWord {
    private String word;
    private boolean used;
    public CrosswordWord(String word) {

        this.word = word;
        used = false;
    }

    public String getWord() {

        return word;
    }

    public boolean isUsed() {

        return used;
    }

    public void setUsed(boolean isUsed) {

        used = isUsed;

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think anyone is going to read through all of that code. You should try to narrow down the problem and only provide the code that's necessary and relevant to your question, so you have a higher chance of getting an answer.

Comment: If I do narrow down this  code I think no one can understand what is going on this code that's why I put whole code. @Keiwan